# Heterogen collection call derived class funtion c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have classes A, B, C.
B and C are derived from A. B has a function foo(). 
If I make an A* array and fill it with B*-s and C*-s then I can't call foo() on the B* element because the compiller will search for it in A.
Is there a way to do it, or A must contain a foo() function too?

Comment: There are a few ways to do it. Yes, you can make a virtual function in `A`. Or you could `dynamic_cast` and test. Or you could implement a visitor pattern for foo() across all the necessary types.

Comment: Could you give examples? Are these "elegant" solutions? Because I could just make to arrays.

Comment: My personal opinion is that what you are doing in general is not elegant. It's elegant to reason about all the objects in the collection as a whole, not think about individual exceptions to the rule. Depending on the situation any one of those could be the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `foo()` is only known for `B` objects.  This means that you have a pointer to `A`, you can't be sure the object has such a function or not. This is why the compiler will complain with an error.

The solution to your issue is polymorphism.

### Alternative 1:  make the function virtual in A

With this approach, you'd have an empty `foo()` function that does nothing for all `A` and `C` objects, but you'd override with the correct function in `B`.

Example:

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo () { cout<<"nothing!"<<endl; }
};
struct B : A {
    void foo () override { cout<<"this is a B object: foo!"<<endl; }
};
struct C : A {};

int main() {
    vector<A*> va; 
    va.push_back (new A);
    va.push_back (new B); 
    va.push_back(new C); 
    for (auto x : va) 
       x->foo(); 
 }
```

Here the [online demo](https://ideone.com/1vHXsa)

For the records, I've use a vector of pointers instead of an array.  But the principle is the same.

Note also that a rule of thumb is that, if you have a virtual function in a class, you should have a virtual destructor as well (I omit it here for the sake of simplicity).

### Alternative 2: make the class polymorphic and use dynamic_cast

With this approach, you'd define the `foo()` only for `B` object.  The trick is when you iterate through your container, you check if the object is a `B` (this requires the object to be polymorphic), and if yes, you invoke the function.

Example:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() {};  // to make A and its descendents polymorphic, you need at least one virtual function
};
struct B : A {
    void foo () { cout<<"this is a B object: foo!"<<endl; }
};
struct C : A {};

int main() {
    vector<A*> va; 
    va.push_back (new A);
    va.push_back (new B); 
    va.push_back(new C); 
    for (auto x : va) {
        auto maybe = dynamic_cast<B*>(x);
        if (maybe) // yes, it's a B*
           maybe->foo(); 
        else cout << "still not a B"<<endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here the [online demo](https://ideone.com/a9fC4c)

The `dynamic_cast` is an intelligent cast: if the type of the object pointed doesn't match the target type, then `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr`.

## Alternative 3: not recommended

The last alternative can be considered if A can't be polymorphic, but if you have a mean knowing an A* to determine if the object is in reaity a B or not. This could be the case, if in A you'd have some information about the type of the object. In this case you could consider a `static_cast`.

This is however not recommended:

- you'd have to manage yourself a way to know the type of the object (so you'd manage manually, what the compiler does automatically when the types are polymorphic).
- if you'd make an error in your `static_cast`, i.e. you think the object is a B but in reality it is not, you'd have an undefined behavior.